# Syntax Error in Create Table Statement

Tags: partitioning, oracle-12c, scripting

I'm using Oracle 12c, I want to create a table with partition by year and subpartition by month like this.

```
create table par.Log_his
(
  ID     NUMBER(20) not null,
  Year           number(4,0), -- Partition
  Monthly            number(2,0)), -- Subpartition
  Log_reason                VARCHAR2(5000),
  Log_detail               VARCHAR2(5000),
    constraint PK_ID primary key (ID)
) PARTITION BY RANGE(Year) INTERVAL (1)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE(Monthly)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
(
SUBPARTITION January VALUES LESS THAN (02)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION February VALUES LESS THAN (03)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION March VALUES LESS THAN (04)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION April VALUES LESS THAN (05)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION May VALUES LESS THAN (06)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION June VALUES LESS THAN (07)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION July VALUES LESS THAN (08)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION August VALUES LESS THAN (09)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION September VALUES LESS THAN (10)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION October VALUES LESS THAN (11)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION November VALUES LESS THAN (12)tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION December VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

When I run it, it raise ORA-00922: missing or invalid option error. How can I fix it ?

My purpose is create a table with auto create partition each year and It save log in 12 month. If I add one more month, the last month will be deleted and this will be done by daly job. Can I define the last month and delete it ?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. create and post  a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe you will found the error without further help

Comment: 2. if it is possible use a tool like sqlplus to execute a command. Usually it will show you a line and the column number of the position where the error occurs,

Comment: Get rid of extra right parenthesis on  Monthly and varchar2 max limit is 4000 characters

Comment: @miracle173 I gave the error above. It position at the end of script

Comment: @Sam Thanks, I changed it

Comment: @PeacePeace No, the error occurs at line 5 of the statement, not at the end. The error message was printed at the end of the script. That is not the same.

Comment: @miracle173 Remove one right parentheses and try again

Comment: @PeacePeace you are a funny guy. I posted two comments on how one can find the error in your statement. And I posted another comment where I mentioned that the error is in the 5th line. And now you think you have to show me the error your statement? I have found the error before I even started to write the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where partition starts from i.e Year

```
create table par.Log_his
(
  ID     NUMBER(20) not null,-- Partition
  Year           number(4,0), -- Subpartition
  Monthly            number(2,0), 
  Log_reason                VARCHAR2(4000),
  Log_detail               VARCHAR2(4000),
  constraint PK_ID primary key (ID)
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE(Year) INTERVAL(1)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE(Monthly)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
(
SUBPARTITION January VALUES LESS THAN (02) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION February VALUES LESS THAN (03) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION March VALUES LESS THAN (04) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION April VALUES LESS THAN (05) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION May VALUES LESS THAN (06) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION June VALUES LESS THAN (07) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION July VALUES LESS THAN (08) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION August VALUES LESS THAN (09) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION September VALUES LESS THAN(10) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION October VALUES LESS THAN(11) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION November VALUES LESS THAN(12) tablespace MONTHLY_PARTITION,
SUBPARTITION December VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE) 
)
(
PARTITION pstart VALUES LESS THAN (2019) -- or more partition as per your requirement
)
/
```